Query not returning expected output with Not exists
I wanted to display those events which is not having D1.
Here is the table schema
Create table #tmp (ID int,stopid int,Events nvarchar(10))

Insert into #tmp    values (1,1,'AF')
Insert into #tmp    values (1,1,'X1')
Insert into #tmp    values (1,2,'D1')
Insert into #tmp    values (1,2,'AF')

Here is the Logic I am trying.
SELECT DISTINCT s.ID
FROM #tmp s
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM #tmp s_inner
    WHERE s_inner.ID = s.ID AND s_inner.stopid=s.stopid and s_inner.Events=s.Events
    AND s.Events = 'D1'
) AND
 s.ID = 1

Expected Output
 ID stopid  Events  
 1  1       AF 
 1  1       X1  

I want to show all the ID which doesnot have D1.

Your expected output seem to indicate that you want all of the records with a StopID that is not associated with Event D1. This excludes (1,2,'D1') directly and (1,2,'AF') by association. Correct? If so, try
SELECT s.ID, StopID, Events
FROM #tmp s
WHERE StopID not in (SELECT StopID from #tmp WHERE Events = 'D1')

Remove and s_inner.Events=s.Events as that too restrictive. @BartMcEndree Do not use NOT IN, it has weird null semantics.

It will still show stopid 2

@Charlieface Your edit does not result in the expected output. You get 3 records. (1,2,'AF') should be excluded. Red Devil wants only output with stopid=1.  I created a fiddle that shows the difference. https://dbfiddle.uk/9xm9dYIl

@BartMcEndree You missed the condition on ID https://dbfiddle.uk/j1CeUQ2s also the last line of the inner query should be AND s_inner.Events = 'D1'

What do you want to happen if there is also a row (2,1,'D1')

Using NOT IN isn't generally the wrong approach. Switch to conditional aggregation here, then this is fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/r6UdeAS_

  SELECT s.ID, StopID, Events 
  FROM #tmp s 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                    FROM #tmp s_inner 
                    WHERE s_inner.Events = 'D1' 
                      AND s_inner.StopID=s.StopID
                   ) 

fiddle



ID
StopID
Events




1
1
AF


1
1
X1




As suggested by Charlieface, I used the "Not Exists" alternative to "Not In".  Results can be surprising if the target column is NULLable . See https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join
